# SAMLBootstrap bean wipes out @Value injection from Cloud Config Server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-saml, spring-cloud-config

When I run my app, metadataFile is always `null` when the bean below is created.   I have a Spring Cloud Config Server which I see is hit before my breakpoint and the YML is successfully retrieved.

Even if the Config Server was down, the SPEL should provide a default.  Has anyone run into `@Value` not evaluating and injecting values before their `@Bean`?   I have many years using XML annotations, so perhaps I never have hit this with Annotation driven config,  but it seems hard to believe I would not have run into this before.   Very confused...

Within it:

```
 @Configuration
 public class Test {

  @Value("${someplace.saml.idp.metadata.file:'classpath:idp-metadata.xml'}")
  String metadataFile;

 @Bean
 MetadataProvider metadataProvider() {
        if(!StringUtils.isBlank(metadataFile) && metadataFile.startsWith("classpath:/")) {
            // do some stuff 
        } else {
            File metadatFile = new File(metadataFile);
        }
 }
```

UPDATE:

I shortened my example above for sake of brevity.   The culprit wiping out the configuration values is this SAMLBootstrap bean.  It seems to be required for annotation-configured Spring SAML2.

```
 @Bean
 SAMLBootstrap samlBootstrap() {
     return new SAMLBootstrap();
 }
```

Comment: How are you accessing `Test` class? Can you post that as well?

Comment: It's in a Spring Boot app and is instantiated by the framework automatically because of the @Configuration tag.

Comment: When I ran your code, I see `@Value` annotated member is already evaluated before getting into `@Bean`. There is nothing special in this code, so I believe there must be some configuration issue in other part of application.

Comment: Did you autowire the Test Class using `@Autowired` in your spring boot app or instantiating something like `new Test()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE 2 (THE SOLUTION):

The SAMLBootstrap bean needs to be declared with static. I found this in the last comment on another post: [Spring Bean without id or name in Java Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111544/spring-bean-without-id-or-name-in-java-config)